# ggplot for different year categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am really struggling with the plots in R. I have to make a plot of logmx versus the age of males in different years in the same plot for males. In this plot there must be 4 lines for "1870-1879", "1940-1949", "1960-1969", "1980-1989"
I made 4 differents subsets with these specific years and tried to combine them but I am new in R and I do not know what I am doing wrong. I saw lots of similar answers but I could not solve it.I need to make it with ggplot2 package.

`males11<-males[445:1555,1:3]`
`males12<-males[4885:5995, 1:3]`
`males13<-males[9325:10435, 1:3]`
`males14<-males[13765:14653, 1:3]`     #for the subsets

`d1 <- data.frame(males11$Age, log(males11$mx), males11$Year)`
`d2 <- data.frame(males12$Age, log(males12$mx), males12$Year)`
`d3 <- data.frame(males13$Age, log(males13$mx), males13$Year)`
`d4 <- data.frame(males14$Age, log(males14$mx), males14$Year)`

`ggplot()`
 + 
  `geom_line(aes(males11$Age, log(males11$mx), colour=males11$Year),  d1)` +
  `geom_line(aes(males12$Age, log(males12$mx), colour=males12$Year), d2)` +
  `geom_line(aes(males13$Age, log(males13$mx), colour=males13$Year), d3)` +
  `geom_line(aes(males14$Age, log(males14$mx), colour=males14$Year), d4)`

Comment: Please supply the output of `dput(head(males[,1:3], 10))` as an edit to your question.

Comment: Please study the documentation. You shouldn't use `$` within `aes`. Why don't you simply do `ggplot(males[c(445:155, 4885:5995, 9325:10435, 13765:14653),], aes(x=Age, y= log(xm), colour=Year)) + geom_line()`?

Comment: I understand your answer, thank you it worked.

Comment: One more question. I made a mistake in the last limit.Is from 2000 to 2007 and it's not 10 years like the others. So, I have to write it seperately? Also, "aes(x=Age, y= log(xm)" Does this calculate the logarithm of each period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build a factor in your original data frame and group by that, similar to this:

```
males$group <- cut(males$Year, 
                   breaks=seq(1799, 2099, 10), 
                   dig.lab=4)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(males[males$group %in% c("(1869-1879]", "(1939-1949]", "(1959-1969]", "(1979-1989]"), ], 
       aes(Age, mx, colour=group)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_log10()
```